# Suppressing native android session timeout warning

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery-mobile

SO I was just wondering if anyone knows of a way to suppress the session timeout dialog that comes up in the android browser.

Basically, I am writing a web app using Jquery Mobile and handle the session check myself, and redirect them to a login page if it's not longer valid.  I would like that warning that pops up not display, or perhaps I could override the behavior using Javascript?  Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: Is it a Toast notification that pops up? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Comment: No, it's more of a system alert kinda thing.  Idk where it's coming from though...

Comment: You wont be able to override that from your site. What does it say? Maybe try fixing the error its reporting or handling it in a different way.

Comment: That's what I did.  I created new logic for handling logging in to continue loading after the user clicks ok.  It will redirect them to the login page I wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I ended up adding a callback to the function to handle the user's session timeout.

```
// if the user's session has timed out, redirect to login
$("body").bind("signin", mobileHomePage.redirectToLogin);
```

So if the session is expired, the signin event is triggered and they are redirected.